# Localization of "(blank)"

Tags: vba, excel, localization

I want to control a slicer in VBA and want to check whether or not empty values are selected, using:

```
If slicerCache.SlicerItems.Item("(blank)").selected = True
```

Empty values automatically get the label `(blank)`. This all works fine, until the workbook is opened on a non-English computer. E.g. in Dutch the label is `(leeg)`, and in French the label is `(vide)`.

How can I get the localized version of this label?

In [this link](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/898136-vba-to-filter-blank-cells-in-pivot-table-but-in-foreign-languages-too.html) the exact same question was asked in 2009, without any answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, and there may be a better method, but it's practical and would work for all languages, provided that the "blank" is always represented by having a starting open paren and an ending close paren, and no other values in the slicer list contain both starting open and ending close  parens.

```
For Each si In SlicerCache.SlicerItems

    'EDIT: I originally wrote this, but the one below is more precise
    'If InStr(si.Name, "(") And InStr(si.Name, ")") Then
    If Left(si.Name,1) = "(" And Right(si.Name,1) = ")" Then 

        If si.Selected = True Then MsgBox si.Name & " is set to True"

    End If

Next
```

Comment: to improve maybe it's better to use left() and right() because the parentheses have to be the first and the last character. EDIT: seems that we had the same idea ;)

Comment: That seems to work fine indeed. Do you have any idea whether or not this would work for each language, especially the ones that don't use 'our' alphabet (e.g. Chinese, Russian)?

Comment: @Wlump, please refer back to my caveats in the post. That is all I can say at the this point without an ability to directly test. It's probably a safe assumption that the blanks will always be given as '([local language version of blank])`